# Can an App like Calm be developed with Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Prior Experience With Programming - Basic Python.

I have made websites using Wordpress & Wix before, but not like proper backend or front end coding experience.

Comment: Yes, I cannot find a reason why can't it be built...

Comment: Of course, it can be developed with flutter. As a 14-year-old, I can state that flutter and dart are both easy to learn and also easy to use. Of course, you need some higher-level experience if you want to develop something that requires complex back- and front-end. I would start with learning the basics of dart and then slowly shift towards learning flutter UI.  And with powerful premade tools like firebase building backends is easy,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create an app like Calm in flutter!